# Defining an Array with Non-Consecutive Indices in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

> Is it possible to define an array with non-consecutive indices in Fortran 90?

---

The following code returns an error (`Error: The module or main program array 'test' at (1) must have constant shape`):

```
program example
  implicit none
  integer, dimension((/1,3/)) :: test
end
```

Is there an alternative way to define such an array or is this simply not allowed?

Comment: *Why* do you think you need this?

Comment: It would help me solve the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50534287/3553449).

Comment: @mzp The answer to your questions are 'no' and 'yes'.  The lower and upper bounds for the dimensions of an array are specification expressions.  A specification expression is a scalar integer expression.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!

Comment: rather than trying madness like that, have you thought about how you could vectorize your problem so that you don't need non-consecutive indices?

Comment: @Fl.pf. I have been thinking about that a lot actually. So far I haven't found a solution. Have you seen the other question I link to in the comment above? Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the type yourself. Here is a messy and inefficient way of doing it.

```
module WeirdArray
  implicit none
  private

  type, public :: Warray
    private
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: indeces
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: vals
  contains
    procedure, pass :: init
    procedure, pass :: get
    procedure, pass :: set
  end type

contains
  subroutine init(this, i, v)
    class(warray), intent(out) :: this
    integer, dimension(:) :: i
    real, dimension(size(i)) :: v
    this%indeces = i
    this%vals = v
  end subroutine init

  function get(this, indx) result(x)
    class(warray), intent(in) :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: indx
    real :: x
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: p
    integer :: i
    p = pack([(i,i=1,size(this%indeces))],this%indeces==indx)
    x = this%vals( p(1) )
  end function get

  subroutine set(this, indx, x)
    class(warray), intent(inout) :: this
    integer, intent(in) :: indx
    real, intent(in) :: x
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: p
    integer :: i
    p = pack([(i,i=1,size(this%indeces))],this%indeces==indx)
    this%vals( p(1) ) = x
  end subroutine set  

end module WeirdArray
```

And you can use it like this:

```
program main
  use weirdArray
  implicit none

  type(Warray) :: wa

  call wa%init([5,12], [10.0, 24.0])

  write(*,*) wa%get(5)
  call wa%set(5, 3.14)
  write(*,*) wa%get(5)
  write(*,*) wa%get(12)

end program main
```